# How do I do a manual fsck?

Tags: fsck, busybox

My pc doesn't want to start saying:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2p cointais a file system with errors, check forced.
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.

/dev/mmcblk0p2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/mmcblk0p2 requires a manual fsck

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

What do I do?

Comment: It would be nice it Ubuntu then prompted with "would you like me to do this now", or is that too convenient?  Non-advanced users are going to struggle to do this sort of thing themselves, and even as a relatively advanced user I can do without this sort of problem.

Answer (score 25):

Run `fsck -y  /dev/mmcblk0p2` at the prompt.

Comment: Do you know what the cause could be and why fsck wants a confirmation?

Comment: Basically, as the error say's, an inconsistency in the filesystem. This can occur because of a hardware problem - bad blocks, disk is dying, a crash or hard shut down, software errors, or similar. Often it relates to failing disk-hardware or crash / hard shutdown,

Comment: The Linux kernel is repairing the file system on boot automatically. Why does fsck ask you if it shall repair it (force)? Is an important part broken or is there just very much broken and it just tries to avoid further data-loss by asking the user?